# Angular2 Table does not build properly after filtering

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have got a problem with filtering a table in angular2.
Filtering works perfectly fine, but deleting the filter [this does happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsrNW.png).

**EDIT**
When I start the program the filter is empty and the view is okay. When I filter for something everything is fine too. If I remove the filter again the elements are there but not in the table anymore... as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsrNW.png).

The table does not rebuild as planned. The Lines are all over the place but not in the table anymore.

I have tried to simplify the html code. If you need to see more, please ask!

```html
<table class="visible-lg-inline visible-md-inline visible-sm-inline table table-condensed">
   <!-- the table head is defined here-->
   <!--TABLE BODY-->
   <tbody *ngFor="let detail of filteredDetails; let posi = index">
       <tr>
           <td (click)="showDetail(detail.itemId)">
               <div><b>{{detail.itemName}}</b></div>
               <div>{{detail.itemId}}</div>
           </td>
           <!-- the other cells as seen in picture-->
       </tr>
       <!-- only shown if showDetail is true -->
       <tr *ngIf="detail.showDetail">
           <td colspan="5">
                <!-- some other divs and another table -->
           </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--FILTER-->
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <!-- some divs -->
          </td>
          <td colspan="3">
             <input value="" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ngModelChange)="filterDetails()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <!-- the button has nothing to do with the filter -->
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-condensed visible-xs-inline fixed">
   <!-- the table head is defined here-->
   <!--TABLE BODY-->
   <tbody *ngFor="let detail of filteredDetails; let posi = index">
       <tr>
           <td (click)="showDetail(detail.itemId)">
               <div><b>{{detail.itemName}}</b></div>
               <div>{{detail.itemId}}</div>
           </td>
           <!-- the other cells as seen in picture-->
       </tr>
       <!-- only shown if showDetail is true -->
       <tr *ngIf="detail.showDetail">
           <td colspan="5">
                <!-- some other divs and another table -->
           </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--FILTER-->
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <!-- some divs -->
          </td>
          <td colspan="3">
             <input value="" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" (ngModelChange)="filterDetails()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <!-- the button has nothing to do with the filter -->
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the simplified Typescript Code (works more less like javascript - thats why I used that tag - hope that´s fine)

```js
public filteredDetails: POSStockDetailWeb[];
public searchValue: string;

//the constructor an the init functions

filterDetails() {
  if (this.searchValue == null || this.searchValue == "")
    this.filteredDetails = this.POSStock.safePOSStockDetails;
  else {
    console.log(this.searchValue);
    this.filteredDetails = [];
    for (let detail of this.POSStock.safePOSStockDetails) {
      if ((detail.itemId.indexOf(this.searchValue) !== -1) || 
          (detail.itemName.indexOf(this.searchValue) !== -1)) {
        this.filteredDetails[this.filteredDetails.length] = detail;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

If you need more input please ask!

Comment: I have tried it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

To solve another problem with my normal table being too large for smartphones, I have used the css visible-sx-inline and for the large table: visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline...

I dont´t realy know why, but they have caused the problem.

@kimy82

Thank you for your help!
I would be interested in the results of the simple version with the classes in it.
(if you still have it and the time for doing so)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and it works When I change the filter it filters. The code I have tried is:

html:

```
 <table>
      <!-- the table head is defined here-->
      <!--TABLE BODY-->
      <tbody *ngFor="let detail of filteredDetails; let posi = index">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <div><b>{{detail.itemName}}</b></div>
               <div>{{detail.itemId}}</div>
           </td>
           <!-- the other cells as seen in picture-->
       </tr>

       </tbody>
       <!--FILTER-->
       <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
               <input value="" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" 
                   (ngModelChange)="filterDetails()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <!-- the button has nothing to do with the filter -->
          </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Ts code:

```
    public filteredDetails: any[] = [];
    public safePOSStockDetails: any[] = [{itemName: 'a', itemId: '1'}, 
      {itemName: 'eea', itemId: '45'}, {itemName: 'eia', itemId: '12'}];
    public searchValue = '';

    filterDetails() {
     if ( this.searchValue === '')
        this.filteredDetails = this.safePOSStockDetails;
     else {
        this.filteredDetails = [];
        for (const detail of this.safePOSStockDetails) {
            if ((detail.itemId.indexOf(this.searchValue) !== -1) || 
            (detail.itemName.indexOf(this.searchValue) !== -1)) {
                this.filteredDetails.push(detail);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The filterprocess itself works perfectly. The only thing which doesn´t is the view (not when I filter) when I delete a filter. Have you tried that? deleting the filterstring?

Comment: Any idea if styles can cause that the table bodies do not stay in the table after filtering?

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the filterstring? it is leaving the the input empty?

Comment: When I leave the input empty it shows all elements and it is the expect. Do you have the  same?

Comment: When I start the program the filter is empty and the view is okay. When I filter for something everything is fine too. If I remove the filter again the elements are there but not in the table anymore... thats what you see in the screenshot from the post.

Comment: Thing is you are right... everything works fine in this simplified version... so its something i havent thought about jet...

Comment: I have updated the code a bit to make it more clear. However, when I try that code I don't get this error you say. Table starts empty, when I filter it filters ok and if I remove the filterstring all elements are displayed in the table. I would suggest it is something else

Comment: i will sent you the complete html

Comment: I see. Could you provide and example of json to fill the fake array _safePOSStockDetails_, so that, I can just try that straight forward?

Comment: I can give you the object definition... and might create some test data...

Comment: Sorry. I do not have enough time to try that. I did a simple test and I was ok. You might have a mispelling error which is stoping that code to work properly. I would suggest to remove each of the ngfo, one by one, till find the error